# Shorten Duplicate Animation WPF Code for Button Controls

Tags: wpf, user-interface, animation

I'm relatively new to Animations in WPF and I have tried to put the animations in `Window.Resources` to no avail. *Note: I tried to find the SO Post for the one I looked at originally, but couldn't find it again.*

Each `Button` has a similar animation, enlarge on `FrameworkElement.MouseEnter` or `FrameworkElement.GotKeyboardFocus` (TAB'd to) and shrink back to original size with `FrameworkElement.MouseLeft` and `FrameworkElement.LostKeyboardFocus`.

How I'm currently doing it means that each on has to do a copy/paste animation in the `Button` WPF Code and change the values per button, which is 1. a mess and 2. annoying.

Example of one of my buttons:

```xml
                  <Button.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.MouseEnter">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation To="180" Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetName="QuitButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                    <DoubleAnimation To="72" Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetName="QuitButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height">
                                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                    <DoubleAnimation To="210" Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetName="QuitButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)">
                                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                    <DoubleAnimation To="444" Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetName="QuitButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)">
                                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
```

How would I go about shortening this and/or placing this in `Windows.Resources` or similar.

The `Width`, `Height` and `Canvas.Top` are all consistant across buttons, the only that actually varies is `Canvas.Left`

Comment: Move the Triggers to `<Style.Triggers>` in a Button Style resource and remove `Storyboard.TargetName`.

Comment: Do this for the 3 that are consistant across buttons, and leave the variable one @Clemens?

Comment: Give it a try... You may perhaps also animate a LayoutTransform that is identical for all the Buttons.

Comment: I will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it might have been 4 months since I posted this, however I rewrote the XAML Code to C#

This is an extract from my code. I wrote it in a seperate `*.cs` file and had 4 events fire towards these functions.

```cs
            DoubleAnimation width = new DoubleAnimation {
                To = buttonDictionary[currentButton.Name][0] * 1.1,
                EasingFunction = eF,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25))
            };
            DoubleAnimation height = new DoubleAnimation {
                To = buttonDictionary[currentButton.Name][1] * 1.1,
                EasingFunction = eF,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25))
            };
            DoubleAnimation cHorizonatal = new DoubleAnimation {
                To = buttonDictionary[currentButton.Name][2] - buttonDictionary[currentButton.Name][0] * 0.05,
                EasingFunction = eF,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25))
            };
            DoubleAnimation cVertical = new DoubleAnimation {
                To = buttonDictionary[currentButton.Name][3] - buttonDictionary[currentButton.Name][1] * 0.05,
                EasingFunction = eF,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25))
            };

            SetStoryboardTargets(currentButton, width, height, cHorizonatal, cVertical, horiString, vertString);

            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
            storyboard.Children.Add(width);
            storyboard.Children.Add(height);
            storyboard.Children.Add(cHorizonatal);
            storyboard.Children.Add(cVertical);

            storyboard.Begin(currentButton);
```

These are the 4 events that control the button animations.

```cs
        private void Button_OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;
            SharedUICode uiEvents = new SharedUICode();
            uiEvents.DoEventExpand(button, ref _buttonDictionary);
        }

        private void Button_OnGotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;
            SharedUICode uiEvents = new SharedUICode();
            uiEvents.DoEventExpand(button, ref _buttonDictionary);
        }

        private void Button_OnMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;
            SharedUICode uiEvents = new SharedUICode();
            uiEvents.DoEventShrink(button, ref _buttonDictionary);
        }

        private void Button_OnLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;
            SharedUICode uiEvents = new SharedUICode();
            uiEvents.DoEventShrink(button, ref _buttonDictionary);
        }
```